# Issues with zeroclipboard not sure where to look

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but we run it as a local file C:\Users\Username\Desktop\common\Common.htm

I have no idea why it is not copying the text box. I have tried many different ways. Am i missing something. I have looked over the documentation but I believe it is poor. 
I have this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<textarea rows="14" id="scratch"></textarea>

 <p class="align-right"><button id="d_clip_button" class="my_clip_button" title="Click me to copy to clipboard." data-clipboard-target="scratch" data-clipboard-text="Default clipboard text from attribute">Copy To Clipboard...</button></p>

    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("scratch").each(function () { }), {
moviePath: 'ZeroClipboard.swf'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in your js console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have issues using the ZeroClipboard file on a locally-hosted file:// page. See the relevant issue / discussion on Github [here](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/478). If you can run a local webserver, you may be able to circumvent the issue.

Just to be clear -- accessing Flash objects locally (using file://) is usually a security issue prohibited by the browser.

Instructions from the ZeroClipboard team for circumventing the file:// issue are [here](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#file-protocol-limitations).

Comment: Oh i thought that meant you can run it in IE or firefox per the document on github. I did not see where it said i would have to run a webserver.

Comment: @matthewmoore, I added a link to instructions from the ZeroClipboard team on what options you have -- basically you will have lots of issues trying to run from file://